# how to use css classes inside angular formly

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo, angular-formly

I am using angular formly. I read the documentation,but they didn't mention how to apply css classes from options.
I am trying to apply kendo ui classes to form fields but of no use.
Can anyone help me?

here is my jsbin

http://jsbin.com/golehimize/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you apply a custom class to the `formly-field` element: https://jsbin.com/foqixe/edit?html,js,output

I'm not sure what classes you're wanting to apply, but this would be the way to do it (see the email field configuration).

Comment: So, basically, just use `className` property or fill in the template

Comment: The option to add className works, but the component doesnt pick up the css code only the classname, any clue on whats missing?